# how to get data from wordpress and submit it by Gravity Form [dynamic population]?

Tags: forms, gravityforms

i am using **Gravity Form** but i want to use it for my posts. i need a form that my users can send me what is wrong about the post. but i want to get the post url and send it in one `input`. by doing so, that input is not needed to be filled (input for post url).

can you guide me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all, i found it myself:

we can do it by one of these three ways:
1- Query String (eng: siteurl.com/form-url/?your_parameter=value)
2- Shortcode (e.g: [gravityforms id=1 field_values='your_parameter=value'] )
3- Hooks

of course we should define a *parameter_name* for that field we need to be filled dynamically

for more information, visit this link:
https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/